# Removing <br> tag with media query also removes spaces before and after <br> tag

Tags: html, css

I need to control the line breaks for a headline. I have a CSS class that controls the visibility of my `<br>` tags. For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .hide-on-mobile {
        display: none
    }

<h1>My long header that needs to have <br class="hide-on-mobile"> a break on desktop</h1>
```

The media query hides the `<br>` tag as expected, **but it also hides the spaces after the tag**. As a result, the two words "have" and "a" run together on mobile. I can add an `&nbsp;` on either side of the `<br>` tag, but it messes up the alignment by a single space.

Any ideas on an alternative solution?

Comment: it doesn't remove the space ... it keeps only one which is good

Comment: It's working as what you intend it to do https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/194/

Answer (score -1):

Could you use `span` instead of `br`? Or any other tag. To break words use `display: block;`, to remove - `display: inline;`